# I need to find only directories in the directory but exclude a linked directory and its link

Tags: bash, grep, find, symlink

I am in a root directory and have some folders inside:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
shortcut -> 0.6
```

I need to list the above directories without both shortcut as well as 0.6 folder. I don't won't to search above this location or within any of these folders. I might have some files here as well but I need to ignore them. New folders with the same naming convention will be added from time to time in this directory, hence this search will be included in the bash script and will generate different results when  new folders will be added and script will be run.

I've tried `find -P . -maxdepth 1 -type d -ls` but no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "be live"?

Comment: New folders will be created there from time to time by different user.

Comment: Sure, but you say "this search needs to be live", and I don't know what that means.

Comment: Good point "live" was really a bad descriptor there, I've just changed it. It is a part of the script that will be producing different results as new folders will be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the prune switch for excluding directories, this should answer your question:

```
find . -path ./your-folder -prune -o -maxdepth 1 -type d -print
```

Comment: `-name '*'` does not do anything as it's always true.

Comment: I agree forgot to remove it

Comment: @Kusalananda, technically, with several `find` implementations including GNU `find`, `-name '*'` excludes the files whose name contains sequences of bytes not forming valid characters in the current locale. IOW, it selects files whose name is valid text in the current locale.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas When it comes to locale-related things, I'm trusting you more than myself.

Comment: What is `./f`? How does this avoid the target of the symbolic link?

Comment: The folder name ./f was renamed to. /your-folder , so it would be more intuitive for readers.

Comment: So `your-folder` should be replaced by `0.6` to work with the example?

Comment: @ Kusalananda Yes indeed!

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of knowing what names are the targets of symbolic links, other than to find the symbolic links and follow them.

We can therefore do this in this way (assumes `bash` version 4.0 or later):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Our blacklist and whitelist associative arrays (whitelist is a misnomer, I know)
# blacklist: keyed on confirmed targets of symbolic links
# whitelist: keyed on filenames that are not symbolic links
#            nor (yet) confirmed targets of symbolic links

declare -A blacklist whitelist

for name in *; do
    if [ -L "$name" ]; then

        # this is a symbolic link, get its target, add it to blacklist
        target=$(readlink "$name")
        blacklist[$target]=1

        # flag target of link in whitelist if it's there
        whitelist[$target]=0

    elif [ -z "${blacklist[$name]}" ]; then
        # This is not a symbolic link, and it's not in the blacklist,
        # add it to the whitelist.
        whitelist[$name]=1
    fi
done

# whitelist now has keys that are filenames that are not symbolic
# links. If a value is zero, it's on the blacklist as a target of a
# symbolic link.  Print the keys that are associated with non-zeros.
for name in "${!whitelist[@]}"; do
    if [ "${whitelist[$name]}" -ne 0 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$name"
    fi
done
```

The script is supposed to be run with your directory as the current working directory, and it makes no assumptions about the names in that directory.

Comment: In `unset whitelist[$target]`, `whitelist[$target]` is a glob, so would need to be quoted, but even then, `unset whitelist"[$target]"` wouldn't work for some values of `$target` like those containing `]` and would even be a command injection vulnerability (try for instance: `x='\`uname>&2\`x' bash -c 'typeset -A a; a[$x]=1; unset "a[$x]"'`. You can actually do `unset 'whitelist[$target]'` though I can't tell if it would be guaranteed to work in future versions, as that's currently not documented.

Comment: Note that that approach assumes the target is expressed as `0.6`, not `./0.6` or `/path/to/0.6`.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want all the files of type *directory* that are not the target of the `shortcut` symlink, with `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
printf '%s\n' *(/^e'{[[ $REPLY -ef shortcut ]]}')
```

- `(...)`: glob qualifier, to further filter files based on other criteria than just name
- `/`: only files of type *directory*
- `^`: negate the following glob qualifiers
- `e'{shell code}'`: select files based on the result (exit status) of the evaluation of the `shell code` (where the files being considered is in `$REPLY`)
- `[[ x -ef y ]]`: returns true if `x` and `y` point to the same file (after symlink resolution). Typically, it does that by comparing the device and inode number of both files (obtained with a `stat()` system call that resolves symlinks).

With GNU `find` (list not sorted, file names prefixed with `./`):

```
#! /bin/sh -
find -L . ! -name . -prune -xtype d ! -samefile shortcut
```

- `-L`: for symlinks, the target of the symlink is considered. That's needed for `-samefile` to do the same thing as `zsh`'s `-ef` above.
- `! -name . -prune`: prune any file but `.`. Same as  `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` but shorter and standard.
- `-xtype d`: now that `-L` is on, we need `-xtype` to match the type of the original file before symlink resolution:
- `-samefile shortcut`: true if the file is the same as `shortcut` (after symlink resolution with `-L`)

To list all directories except those that are the target of *any* of the symlinks in the current directories:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat
typeset -A ignore
for f (*(N@-/)) {
   zstat -H s -- $f &&
     ignore[$s[device]:$s[inode]]=1
}

printf '%s\n' *(/^e'{zstat -H s -- $REPLY && ((ignore[$s[device]:$s[inode]]))}')
```

Note that the `zsh`-bases ones ignore the hidden files. Add the `D` glob qualifier or set the `dotglob` option to consider them.